# Best way to remove trailing zeros from a Decimal

Tags: vb.net

I have a calculation that returns a decimal with a maximum of two decimal places. What I'd like to achieve is a result that doesn't include decimal zeros, so 8.00 is shown as 8, 8.10 is shown as 8.1 and 8.12 is shown as 8.12.

I've been all over the math functions and can't find anything to achieve this - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show the code for your "calculation"?  Does it return a string?  Where are you seeing the extra zeros?

Comment: What Steven Doggart is trying to get at is that trailing zero's are a a property of your decimal conversion to a string and don't actually have to do with the number itself. Please provide more information on how the number you are trying to edit is being converted to a string or displayed.

Comment: Have a look at this MSDN article on Standard Numeric Format Strings. This applies to the .NET framework 4.5

Comment: Thanks all for taking the time to look at this - really appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: @BenjaminLeinweber Actually the decimal number format does include trailing zeroes. `1.010m.ToString()` gives a different result to `1.01m.ToString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Benjamin Leinweber pointed out in one of the comments it's probably a product of it being displayed as a string.  That said, you could take the duct tape approach and just lop off the trailing digits you don't want like this (who doesn't love duct tape every so often):

```
    ' Hacky, I did this because Visual Studio removes the 0 in the editor
    Dim num As Decimal = CDec("8.10")

    ' This will now output 8.10
    Console.WriteLine(num)

    ' Put it in a string then trim off the 0's and then the decimal place if it then happens to be at the end
    Dim buf As String = num.ToString
    buf = buf.TrimEnd("0")
    buf = buf.TrimEnd(".")

    ' This will output 8.1
    Console.WriteLine(buf)
```

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't spotted the code added by another developer that was converting the decimal to a string with two decimal places - TrimEnd sorts it out perfectly.

Comment: if my decimal value is 12.00 the method buf = buf.TrimEnd(New String({"0", "."})) will return 12. which is not a well formed string

Comment: @whiterabbitj You are correct, it does seem to have that effect where the decimal isn't removed in that scenario.  I'll update my answer, splitting the TrimEnd into two statements remedies that.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the VB Decimal data type? If so then read this from the MSDN documentation...

```
Trailing Zeros. Visual Basic does not store trailing zeros in a Decimal literal. 
However, a Decimal variable preserves any trailing zeros acquired computationally. 
The following example illustrates this. 

Dim d1, d2, d3, d4 As Decimal 

d1 = 2.375D
d2 = 1.625D
d3 = d1 + d2
d4 = 4.000D

MsgBox("d1 = " & CStr(d1) & ", d2 = " & CStr(d2) & 
     ", d3 = " & CStr(d3) & ", d4 = " & CStr(d4))

The output of MsgBox in the preceding example is as follows: 

    d1 = 2.375, d2 = 1.625, d3 = 4.000, d4 = 4
```

So since the Decimal data type holds on to significant digits in a calculation then you may want to convert the data type to double and use a custom format like `{0:#.##}` for display

[MSDN Decimal Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtba3z33.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`.ToString("###")` or however many octothorpes for however many to the left of the decimal.

If you want to have... say, 2 decimal places:

`.ToString("###.##")`

Comment: If you are needing this for formatting purposes, this is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using TrimEnd function :

```
Dim number1 As Double = 8.0
Dim number2 As Double = 8.1
Dim number3 As Double = 8.12
Console.WriteLine(number1.ToString("N2").TrimEnd("0"c).TrimEnd("."c))
Console.WriteLine(number2.ToString("N2").TrimEnd("0"c).TrimEnd("."c))
Console.WriteLine(number3.ToString("N2").TrimEnd("0"c).TrimEnd("."c))
```

Consider that formatting with "F0" will remove 1000 separators too.

Answer (score 0):

From what you are describing, it sounds like you are using a `Fixed-point` format when you should be using a `Number` format or a `General` format.

This sample code taken from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-8) shows how to use the `Number` format:

```
Dim dblValue As Double = -12445.6789
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
' Displays -12,445.68
Console.WriteLine(dblValue.ToString("N1", _
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE")))
' Displays -12 445,7 

Dim intValue As Integer = 123456789
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
' Displays 123,456,789.0
```

For a complete list of formatters, have a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies to different cultures and works with integer numbers ends with Zero

`
Public Module DecimalExt

```
<Extension()>
Function ToStringWithoutZeros(ByRef value As Decimal) As String
    Dim buf As String = value.ToString("n10")
    buf = buf.TrimEnd("0").TrimEnd(",").TrimEnd(".")
    Return buf
End Function
```

End Module
`

Answer (score 0):

I think You can try with Val Function

Like we we have a Decimal Value like
8.00
8.01
8.590

Then after using the `Val()` function it will convert this decimals to
`Dim number as Decimal = 8.00`

```
`Msgbox(Val(number))` // will gives you 8
```